# Android - reliably ping server every few seconds

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

I have a business requirement that the Android app needs to report to the server every few seconds (all the time, 24/7) on a dedicated device. 
First I thought that it can be done with the PeriodicWorkRequest, but I've read its minimum interval is 15mins.

What would be the best way to achieve this? What mechanism I can rely on to be sure that the process won't be killed?

Is it possible to do with WorkManager? Should I have a foreground service with a loop?

Comment: "What would be the best way to achieve this?" -- use a different mobile operating system than Android. Or, build a custom ROM for your dedicated device, where you can create a Linux daemon that can implement your ping. "Is it possible to do with WorkManager?" -- no, it will not perform work that frequently. "Should I have a foreground service with a loop?" -- you could use `ScheduledExecutorService` to avoid the loop. A foreground service is the closest an ordinary Android app can get to an unkillable process. It can still be killed. Plus, Doze mode will interfere with your Internet access.

Comment: @CommonsWare It's a dedicated device, the client is an owner, so we should be able to set the doze mode off. It should run in the lock task mode, half time with the screen on, half time with screen off.

Comment: "so we should be able to set the doze mode off" -- that depends a lot on the device manufacturer. Some manufacturers have their own "super Doze" that does not seem to be reliably controllable by the user.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info!

Comment: Knowing the device OEM and model would help in this case. Some enterprise devices have custom APIs to disable Doze mode.
Some AOSP devices, have Doze mode disabled (e.g. rugged Android devices used in Warehouses). knowing OEM and model can help in this case.As @CommonsWare replied, a Foreground service is the as close as you can get to what you want on a vanilla GMS android device.
If this devices are managed (DO or PO), you can look into having a DPC to access some additional API's 
* https://developers.google.com/android/work/
* https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices

Comment: You should try and understand the intention of the business requirement and figure out the real reason why the client _must_ ping the server. You are going to absolutely destroy battery - dedicated device or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could schedule it the other way. Make your server send a notification to your android device,could be done easily via firebase. Then handle notification in your app and report back to the server.

Comment: Will the notification be received when the device screen is off?